# Linux - sed - Edit java opts from config file

Tags: linux, sed

My current Java config needs to be updated as below? It implements multiple logics & if 1 works, the other fails. Pls share sed command.

Current:

```
    default_value JAVA_LOGGING_OPTS " \
            -DlogFile=${STDOUT_LOG_PATH}/${COMPONENT_INSTANCE}-Cache-Server.log \
            -Dlog4j.configuration=file:${BASE_DIR}/sysconfig/log4j.properties\
            -Dtangosol.coherence.log=log4j \
            -Dtangosol.coherence.log.level=5"
```

Needed:

```
    default_value JAVA_LOGGING_OPTS " \
            -DlogFile=${STDOUT_LOG_PATH}/${COMPONENT_INSTANCE}-Cache-Server.log \
            -Dlog4j.configuration=file:${BASE_DIR}/sysconfig/log4j.properties\
            -Dtangosol.coherence.log=log4j \
            -Dtangosol.coherence.log.level=5 \
            -Xloggc:${BASE_DIR}/logs/gc/gc-${INSTANCE}.log \
            -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation \
            -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 \
            -XX:GCLogFileSize=10m \
            -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 \
            -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps \
            -XX:+PrintGCDetails"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting lines with `sed` after a certain block is quite easy with [selecting lines by text matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses); [the `s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)'s *regexp* `"$` assures that only the closing quote at the end of line is replaced.

```
sed '/default_value JAVA_LOGGING_OPTS "/,/"/s?"$? \\\
            -Xloggc:${BASE_DIR}/logs/gc/gc-${INSTANCE}.log \\\
            -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation \\\
            -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 \\\
            -XX:GCLogFileSize=10m \\\
            -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 \\\
            -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps \\\
            -XX:+PrintGCDetails"?' Current >Needed
```